# How to make a conditional column using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
Group   Task    Status   
1       A       Success
1       B       Success
1       C       Success
2       A       Success
2       B       Success
2       C       Failed
```

I want to create a conditional logic that groups the dataframe by the group. If ALL status for the group are `Success` then the Overall_Status is `Success`. If ANY status for the group is `Failed` then Overall_Status is `Failed`.

```
Group   Task    Status         Overall_Status
1       A       Success        Success
1       B       Success        Success
1       C       Success        Success
2       A       Success        Failed
2       B       Success        Failed
2       C       Failed         Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all values are `Success` per groups with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['Status'].eq('Success').groupby(df['Group']).transform('all')
df['Overall_Status'] = np.where(mask, 'Success','Failed')
print (df)
   Group Task   Status Overall_Status
0      1    A  Success        Success
1      1    B  Success        Success
2      1    C  Success        Success
3      2    A  Success         Failed
4      2    B  Success         Failed
5      2    C   Failed         Failed
```

Or get groups with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal `Success` and create mask by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask1 = df['Group'].isin(df.loc[df['Status'].ne('Success'), 'Group'].unique())
```

Another idea is test at least one `Failed` per groups with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
mask1 = df['Status'].eq('Failed').groupby(df['Group']).transform('any')
df['Overall_Status'] = np.where(mask1, 'Failed', 'Success')

print (df)
   Group Task   Status Overall_Status
0      1    A  Success        Success
1      1    B  Success        Success
2      1    C  Success        Success
3      2    A  Success         Failed
4      2    B  Success         Failed
5      2    C   Failed         Failed
```

Comment: when I tried this it said everything was ```Failed```.

Comment: @Josh - What is `print(df['Status'].tolist())` ?

Comment: @Josh - Because it seems some whitespace or similar problem with values `Success`

Comment: ['Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'Succesful', 'FAILED']

Comment: Please note, I am doing this on larger/real data, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @Josh - so change in my solution `Success` to `Succesful` only.

Comment: this is what I used.. `mask = new_df['Status'].eq('Successful').groupby(new_df['Process ID']).transform('all')
new_df['DAG Status'] = np.where(mask, 'Successful', 'FAILED')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197611/discussion-between-jezrael-and-josh).